# I2C on atmega168/328 using interrupts

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, i2c, interrupts, twi

I have the following I2C configuration with an ATmega168 (1 MHz) as the master and an Arduino Uno (16 MHz) as the slave.

[image]

The command for the LED connected to the slave comes from the master and vice versa. I can't get the I2C to work. The LEDs are at whatever value I initially set ledValue to be, and it is not getting it from the slave/master.

The code running on the master.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint8_t slaveAddress = 5;
volatile uint8_t ledValue = 0;
volatile uint8_t refValue = 100;
volatile uint8_t rw;

void send_start(){ TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEA) | (1 << TWSTA) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWIE); }

void send_stop(){ TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEA) | (1 << TWSTO) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWIE); }

void send_data(){ TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEA) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWIE); }

ISR(TWI_vect)
{
    volatile uint8_t status = TWSR & 0xF8;
    if(status == 0x08) // start send successfully - now send SLA+R/W
    {
        TWDR = (slaveAddress << 1) + rw;
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x50 || status == 0x58) //receive mode - data received - read it - send stop
    {
        ledValue = TWDR;
        send_stop();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x18 || status == 0x20) //transmit mode - SLA+W successfully sent - now send data
    {
        TWDR = refValue; //data to be transmitted
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x28 || status == 0x30) //transmit mode - data successfully sent - now send stop
    {
        send_stop();
        return;
    }
    //anything else - clear TWINT
    TWCR |= (1 << TWINT);
}

void initialize_pwm()
{
    DDRD |= (1 << DDD3);
    TCCR2A |= (1 << COM2B1) | (1 << WGM20);
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS20);
}

int main(void)
{
    initialize_pwm();
    TWBR = 0;
    //TWSR &= ~((1 << TWPS1) | (1 << TWPS0)); // prescaler 1
    // SCL = 1 MHz/(16 + 2*0*1) = 1/16 MHz
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWIE);
    sei();

    while(1)
    {
        rw = 1; //read
        send_start();
        _delay_ms(1000);
        OCR2B = ledValue;
        rw = 0; //write
        send_start();
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The code running on the slave.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint8_t slaveAddress = 5;
volatile uint8_t ledValue = 0;
volatile uint8_t refValue = 100;

void send_data(){ TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEA) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWIE); }

ISR(TWI_vect)
{
    volatile uint8_t status = TWSR & 0xF8;
    if(status == 0xA8) // trasmit mode - master sent SLA+R - now send data back
    {
        TWDR = refValue; //data to be transmitted
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x80 || status == 0x88) // receive mode - master sent data after SLA+W - read it
    {
        ledValue = TWDR;
        TWCR |= (1 << TWINT);
        return;
    }
    //anything else - clear TWINT
    TWCR |= (1 << TWINT);
}

void initialize_pwm()
{
    DDRD |= (1 << DDD3);
    TCCR2A |= (1 << COM2B1) | (1 << WGM20);
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS20);
}

int main(void)
{
    initialize_pwm();
    TWAR = (slaveAddress << 1);
    TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN) | ( 1 << TWIE);
    sei();

    while(1)
    {
        _delay_ms(1000);
        OCR2B = ledValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug the problem?

Comment: How did you programm the master?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a ground connection between the top and bottom busses on the breadboard.  You should also have a bypass capacitor between Vcc and Gnd on the chip on the breadboard. You don't show a Vcc connection to the breadboard.

Comment: @MathieuL, I used the usbasp.

Comment: @PeterBennett, The master is powered as shown in http://goo.gl/njVvxr. The slave is powered using the usb port on my Mac. I did not show all those details. I made sure they have a common ground. Will that not suffice.

Comment: @NickJohnson, I tried to get an LED blinking each time the ISR is called. On the master it remains ON and on the slave it is OFF. Any other pointers.

Comment: Well, you could start by adding debugging statements that output to the UART - or even just toggle IO pins - to let you determine what code is running, when.

Comment: For the test purposes try not to use the ISRs. Send start/data/stop from the master every second or so in a loop and display what you get in the slave.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have got things working. But there is one minor issue that bugs me, and if any of you know what is going on that'll be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to arrive at an answer to my own question.

Master code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

volatile uint8_t ledValue = 0;
volatile uint8_t refValue = 0;
volatile uint8_t status;
volatile uint8_t pstatus = 0;
volatile uint8_t rw;
volatile bool receiveQ = true;
volatile bool transmitQ = false;

void send_start(){ TWCR &= ~(1 << TWSTO); TWCR |= (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTA); }

void send_stop(){ TWCR &= ~(1 << TWSTA);  TWCR |= (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTO); }

void send_data(){ TWCR &= ~((1 << TWSTA) | (1 << TWSTO)); TWCR |= (1 << TWINT); }

void toggle(){PORTB ^= (1 << PORTB0);}

ISR(TWI_vect)
{
    status = TWSR & 0xF8;
    if(status == 0x08 || status == 0x10)
    {
        pstatus = 1;
        TWDR = rw;
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x38)
    {
        pstatus = 2;
        send_start();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x40)
    {
        pstatus = 3;
        TWCR &= ~(1 << TWEA);
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x48)
    {
        pstatus = 4;
        send_start();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x50)
    {
        pstatus = 5;
        ledValue = TWDR;
        TWCR &= ~(1 << TWEA);
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x58)
    {
        pstatus = 6;
        ledValue = TWDR;
        receiveQ = false;
        transmitQ = true;
        send_stop();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x18 || status == 0x20)
    {
        pstatus = 7;
        TWDR = refValue; //data to be transmitted
        send_data();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x28 || status == 0x30)
    {
        pstatus = 8;
        receiveQ = true;
        transmitQ = false;
        send_stop();
        return;
    }
    if((pstatus == 8 || pstatus == 6)){toggle();}
    pstatus = 0;
    send_stop();
}

void initialize_pwm()
{
    DDRD |= (1 << DDD3);
    TCCR2A |= (1 << COM2B1) | (1 << WGM20);
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS20);
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB0);
    //uint8_t slaveAddress = 5;
    initialize_pwm();
    TWBR = 10;
    TWCR = (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWIE);
    sei();

    while(1)
    {
        if(receiveQ)
        {
            rw = 11; //BitShiftLeft[5, 1] + 1, read
            refValue += 5;
            if(refValue > 255){refValue = 0;}
            send_start();
        }
        _delay_ms(100);
        OCR2B = ledValue;
        if(transmitQ)
        {
            rw = 10; //BitShiftLeft[5, 1], write
            send_start();
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Slave code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint8_t ledValue = 0;
volatile uint8_t refValue = 0;
volatile uint8_t status;

void send_ack(){ TWCR |= (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEA);}

void send_n_ack(){ TWCR &= ~(1 << TWEA); TWCR |= (1 << TWINT);}

void toggle(){PORTB ^= (1 << PORTB0);}

ISR(TWI_vect)
{
    status = TWSR & 0xF8;
    if(status == 0xA8 || status == 0xB0)
    {
        TWDR = refValue;
        send_n_ack();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0xB8)
    {
        TWDR = refValue;
        send_n_ack();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0xC0 || status == 0xC8)
    {
        send_ack();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x60 || status == 0x68 || status == 0x70|| status == 0x78)
    {
        send_ack();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x80 || status == 0x90)
    {
        ledValue = TWDR;
        send_n_ack();
        return;
    }
    if(status == 0x88 || status == 0x98 || status == 0xA0)
    {
        send_ack(); 
        return;
    }
    toggle();
    send_ack();
}

void initialize_pwm()
{
    DDRD |= (1 << DDD3);
    TCCR2A |= (1 << COM2B1) | (1 << WGM20);
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS20);
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB0);
    initialize_pwm();
    TWAR = 10; //BitShiftLeft[5, 1];
    TWCR = (1 << TWEN) | ( 1 << TWIE) | (1 << TWEA);
    sei();

    while(1)
    {
        refValue += 5;
        if(refValue > 255){refValue = 0;}
        _delay_ms(100);
        OCR2B = ledValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything works fine, but I have a follow-up question which I have not been able to figure out. Right after sending a stop, the master goes into status 0x00 ("bus error due to illegal START or STOP condition"). I recover from it by sending another stop. But why is it happening in the first place, and can it be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, I2C communication will not work inside an ISR. A lot of other things also don't work (properly) inside an ISR, digitalWrite for instance. Some time ago I was trying to use an MPU6050 sensor (I2C) with function calls inside an ISR, but that didn't work so I had to change to an analog sensor. Just search "function call from ISR" to confirm.

Comment: It was a tempting argument, (and part of me was hoping you were right), but I decided to persevere a tad bit more. :)